# Complex Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am getting below value from group_concat() in a veriable in mysql

```
abc#123#def#456#xyz#789#10111#
```

Now I want to run query / stord procedure which can break this string in columns like

abc | 123 |def | 456 | xyz | 789 | 10111 |

Comment: dun need to be so cumbersome, when u `group_concat` dun use `#` as separator, change it to `|` or change the query/procedure to be accept variable of separator

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the query to return the column names if that's what I really wanted.  It seems a waste of CPU to ask MySQL to put the strings together and then take them apart on the middle tier.

Have two queries: one to return the concatenated values and another just the raw values: "abc", "123", "def", etc.

Comment: first query is getting values of a set like user from different rows. have to change them in columns using query

Comment: still makes no sense - less now, actually.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
drop procedure if exists foo;

delimiter #

create procedure foo
(
in p_csv varchar(1024)
)
proc_main:begin

declare v_token varchar(255);
declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_token_idx int unsigned default 1;

    if p_csv is null or length(p_csv) <= 0 then
        leave proc_main;
    end if;

    -- split the string into tokens and put into an in-memory table...

    create temporary table tokens(
        token_id smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key, 
        token varchar(255)
    )engine = memory;   

    while not v_done do
    set v_token = trim(substring(p_csv, v_token_idx, 
      if(locate('#', p_csv, v_token_idx) > 0, 
                locate('#', p_csv, v_token_idx) - v_token_idx, length(p_csv))));

      if length(v_token) > 0 then
        set v_token_idx = v_token_idx + length(v_token) + 1;
                insert into tokens (token) values(v_token);
      else
        set v_done = 1;
      end if;
    end while;

    select * from tokens order by token_id;

    drop temporary table if exists tokens;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

call foo('abc#123#def#456#xyz#789#10111#');
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want output in single row (7 Columns)  not 7 rows

Comment: shall i do that for you then ?